# Window function filter not ignoring rollup null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a simple table that contains films:

```
CREATE TABLE public.films
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    title character varying(255),
    release_year integer
)
```

I also have a query that calculates the number of films by year, the total count of all films (using `ROLLUP`) and a window function that add the total number of films to each row:

```
SELECT 
    release_year, 
    COUNT(*),
    SUM(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE release_year IS NOT NULL)) OVER ()
FROM films 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(release_year)
```

I added the `FILTER (WHERE release_year IS NOT NULL)` part because I wanted to ignore the aggregated row produced by `ROLLUP`. Surprisingly this filtering doesn't work:

```
| release_year | count | sum |
 ----------------------------
|       [null] |   225 | 450 | 
|         2014 |    57 | 450 | <--- sum should be 225 everywhere
|         2015 |    53 | 450 |
|         2016 |    57 | 450 |
|         2017 |    58 | 450 |
```

I know some other possible ways to solve this, like moving the window function to an outside query or partitioning by `release_year IS NOT NULL`, but I'm very curious why this particular case doesn't work as I expected. What do I miss?

I use Postgres 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FILTER doesn't work OVER the ROLLUP since it 'renders' while ROLLUP is being made.

If you remove the `SUM` you'll see:

```
SELECT
-- Adding window function row_number for test:
    row_number() OVER() as rn,
    release_year,
    COUNT(*),
-- Removing SUM and OVER for test:
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE release_year IS NOT NULL)
FROM films 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(release_year)
```

This outputs something like:

```
rn  | release_year | count | sum |
----+--------------+-------+------
1   |       [null] |   225 | 225 | 
2   |         2014 |    57 | 57  |
3   |         2015 |    53 | 53  |
4   |         2016 |    57 | 57  |
5   |         2017 |    58 | 58  |
```

Since `FILTER` works on the ROLLUP and not on the 'final' table, it does not find any NULL release_year, and because of the ROLLUP, it sums all release_year's.

Since the Window Functions 'renders' over the 'final' table, when you add the `SUM() OVER()` it sums all in the column; see rn column, it counts all becouse it 'renders' after the ROLLUP.

**EDIT (Furthermore):**

There is an order in which postgresql computes (I say renders) a query. Generally it starts with the `WHERE` clause, then group by, then aggregation, and always at the end it does window functions.

If you run `EXPLAIN` you can see it more clearly:

```
                                  QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 WindowAgg  (cost=XXX.XX..XXX.XX rows=XXX width=XX)
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=XXX.XX..XXX.XX rows=XXX width=XX)
         Group Key: release_year
         Group Key: ()
         ->  Sort  (cost=XXX.XX..XXX.XX rows=XXXX width=X)
               Sort Key: release_year
               ->  Seq Scan on films  (cost=X.X..XX.XX rows=XXXX width=X)
```

**First**, it does the `WHERE` clause, but since there is no `WHERE` on the query, it gets all the rows from table films (Scan on films).

**Second**, it does the group and orders by release_year since it is in the `GROUP BY ROLLUP` clause (Sort).

**Third**, it runs the aggregation function `COUNT` over the grouped data (GroupAggregate). Since `FILTER` is just a substitution of `CASE WHEN` it runs at this point, over the grouped data. More info about FILTER [here](https://medium.com/little-programming-joys/the-filter-clause-in-postgres-9-4-3dd327d3c852)

**Lastly**, it runs the window functions over the aggregation (WindowAgg).

**Some Notes:**

When I say 'over', I mean that internally postgresql has kind of a temporal table -this 'final' table I refer above, actually a set of data- over which it runs all the functions or clauses you use in a query.

After running the window functions it returns a RESULT table, that is what you get. But in the middle, postgresql uses sets of data to get what you asked.

**Conclusion**

In that sense, your query doesn't returns what you would like because the FILTER works over the grouped data, not the set of data where there is a NULL on release_year. Only **window functions** have access to this NULL since they **work on the last set of data before it is returned to you**, and since window functions have limited uses, you would have to query over this RESULT table to get what you want.

Nevertheless, if you want to read more:

- [Reading a PostgreSQL EXPLAIN](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/reading-an-explain-analyze-query-plan)
- [Understanding Window Functions](http://tapoueh.org/blog/2013/08/understanding-window-functions/)
- [Filter Clause in PostgreSQL](https://medium.com/little-programming-joys/the-filter-clause-in-postgres-9-4-3dd327d3c852)

And more in the postgresql manual:

- [PostgreSQL Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) (Group By)
- [PostgreSQL Aggregate Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite get it. You write that "FILTER works on the ROLLUP and not on the 'final' table", but also "Window Functions 'renders' over the 'final' table". Clearly there is something I don't know about window functions. Can you maybe provide a link to a documentation discussing this particular thing?

Comment: Done, I've updated my answer with more info and links if you want to read more.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense now. Thank you for the clarification :)